# Keyboard shortcuts on invisible elements in the browser

Tags: javascript, css, keyboard, markup

I'd like to assign keyboard shortcuts to the buttons on my pages.

It turns out that doing it straight in the markup leads to a dangerous side effect: a shortcut fires the click event even when the button is invisible.

I can resort to dynamically set/unset shortcuts in my front end controller but it seems a bit kludge. Is there a more elegant way to do it? Many thanks!

Comment: Please show a sample of what you've got.

Comment: I'd stick to unsetting the shortcuts.

Comment: @LeeTaylor
<button id='myButton' accessKey='M' style='display:none' onclick='javascript:alert("I am your button");'>My Button</button>
...
When the page loads, pressing <ALT>+M fires the alert window.

Comment: @Alex - Please update your question with that code

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like this

```
var shortcuts = {
    49: document.getElementById("button"), //character "1"
    50: document.getElementById("button2") //character "2"
};

var isVisible = function(el) {
    return !(el.style.display === "none" || el.style.visibility === "hidden");
};

var bindEvent = function(el, event, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener){
    el.addEventListener(event, handler, false); 
  } else if (el.attachEvent){
    el.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
  }
};

bindEvent(window, "keydown", function(e) {
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if(typeof shortcuts[charCode] !== "undefined" && shortcuts[charCode] && isVisible(shortcuts[charCode])) {
        shortcuts[charCode].click();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z2baQ/

Comment: Didnt know it was possible to add numeric values as a object property key. Thanks

Comment: You can use an array if you like. Also, you can select this as the accepted answer by pressing the checkmark

Comment: @Nile I couldn't use your fiddle as is, it does not set/unset shortcuts. Also, could you elaborate on how your solution can be used to "conventional" shortcuts, i.e. <ALT>+<symbol> ?

Comment: By hiding the element using css `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` you've automatically unset the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing as shown below, which does exactly what I wanted: the shortcut for hidden button does not work, but the one for a visible one does.

```
<head>

    $(document).ready(function () {
         var self = 'document_ready';
         assignListeners();
     });

    var assignListeners = function() {
        $('#btn1').on('click', function(){
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none')
                realListener1();
        });
        $('#btn2').on('click', function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                realListener2();
            }
        });
    };


    var realListener1 = function() {
        alert('Button 1 clicked')
    };
    var realListener2 = function() {
        alert('Button 2 clicked')
    };


</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<div>
<button id="btn1" accesskey="Z" style="display: none;">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2" accesskey="X" >Button 2</button>
</div>

</body>
```